# openapi generation - initialize objects

Tags: java, openapi, openapi-generator

Iam using openapi-generator-maven-plugin for generating code from my yml files.

```
<groupId>org.openapitools</groupId>
<artifactId>openapi-generator-maven-plugin</artifactId>
<version>3.3.4</version>
```

When generating objects from the yml the generated code always generate objects and initilize them with null.

**For example:**

```
public class Foo   {
  @JsonProperty("bar")
  private Bar bar = null;
}
```

**Is there a way that the object is initialized with the object itself like:**

```
public class Foo   {
  @JsonProperty("bar")
  private Bar bar = new Bar();
}
```

Comment: It initializes fields using default value from Your constract file - they need to be primitives. However You can configure generator so that it will use Your template whenre You can achieve this. [Check the plugin param called](https://github.com/OpenAPITools/openapi-generator/blob/master/modules/openapi-generator-maven-plugin/README.md) `templateDirectory`

Answer (score 0):

Some snippets and links which can help You.

Plugin config in `pom.xml`:

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.openapitools</groupId>
    <artifactId>openapi-generator-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>4.2.2</version>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <goals>
                <goal>generate</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
                <inputSpec>${project.basedir}/docs/openapi/api.yml</inputSpec>
                <generatorName>java</generatorName>
                <templateDirectory>docs/openapi/template</templateDirectory>
            </configuration>
        </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>
```

Copy default templates e.g. from [Java module of OpenAPI generator](https://github.com/OpenAPITools/openapi-generator/tree/master/modules/openapi-generator/src/main/resources/Java) and put all mustache files inside some directory in Your project - check plugin configuration (in my case it is `docs/openapi/template`).

Find the file `pojo.mustache` which is a template to generate a POJO files.

You need to understand some basic Mustache syntax at this point. Find sych a fragment:

```
[...]
{{^isContainer}}
  private {{{datatypeWithEnum}}} {{name}}{{#defaultValue}} = {{{.}}}{{/defaultValue}};
{{/isContainer}}
[...]
```

Change to whatever You want, e.g.:

```
[...]
{{^isContainer}}
private {{{datatypeWithEnum}}} {{name}}{{#defaultValue}} = {{{.}}}{{/defaultValue}}{{^defaultValue}}{{^isPrimitiveType}} = new {{datatypeWithEnum}}(){{/isPrimitiveType}}{{/defaultValue}};
{{/isContainer}}
[...]
```

This template snippet will generate `new TypeYouWantToUse()` parts for every non primitive datatype.

Be aware that this is just a simple example how to proceed further. There are many corner cases e.g. `enum` handling.

FUrther readings:

- [OpenApi generator](https://github.com/OpenAPITools/openapi-generator)
- [OpenApi generator templating documentation](https://openapi-generator.tech/docs/templating)